# Use of mkdir() in C++

Tags: c++, unix

just wanted to know if there are any drawbacks to using mkdir in C++ code? I've heard about the 'evils' of system and popen, particularly when talking about security concerns and memory usage... are there similar problems when using mkdir/getcwd/other direct unix commands like that in code? Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a cross-platform library to do grungy stuff like this.  Boost is an example.

Comment: I don't really know about any drawbacks, except portability, but if you need alternative solutions, you can look at boost or qt for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue you may run into while using `mkdir`, `getcwd` and the likes will be porting your program to different platforms.

Other than that, it is perfectly safe to use them.

Also - `popen` and `system` are not **evil**, but may be dangerous if used without care - something that applies to most system APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the input- any thoughts on memory usage of these functions?

Comment: It's hard to say something useful about memory usage, if we are not talking about a specific platform.

Comment: How about Linux specifically?

Answer (score 1):

It's not portable to other OS's. If you are concerned about portability, try using Boost:

```
boost::filesystem::path dir("/path/to/newdir");
boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
```

Comment: that is not the same functionality as `mkdir` though

Comment: @stijn, that's right. I missed the create_directory statement :)